# Woocommerce add to cart monly or yearly payment

Tags: wordpress

I new in subscription payments need help regarding to subscription payments. I am using
   WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $parent_id ); 
for adding product to the cart.
How can i add product to cart for monthly or yearly periodically payment.
what parameter should i send ?

WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $parent_id, 'yearly' ); 
or what ?

Comment: You have to create a subscription product or a subscription first. Then I guess you can actually add it using your code. You can read more about subscriptions [here](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/subscriptions/subscription-product-vs-subscription/)

Comment: I have created the subscription product

Comment: i just want to know what should i code for adding subscription period in this function or in if there is some other? 
WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $parent_id, 'yearly' ); or WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $parent_id, 'monthly' ); or what?

Comment: The subscription period, duration and settings are set in the subscription product. Notice that a subscription is not a regular Woocommerce product. You must have installed the subscriptions extension. Then you can add a subcripction product using add_to_cart.

Comment: I have purchased and installed the subscription extension. Now i am doing custom changing where i need to add product to cart with product id and its subscription period interval monthly or yearly...

Answer (score 0):

The subscription interval is set in the product page.

[image: Subscription billing interval]

If you want a subscription to have different intervals and want to choose them grammatically you must create a variable subscription and change the period in each variation.

[image]

Then when you add the product to cart you choose what variation are you adding

```
add_to_cart( $product_id, $quantity, $variation_id);
```

This is all available parameters of add_to_cart function:

```
    /**
     * Add a product to the cart.
     *
     * @param int $product_id contains the id of the product to add to the cart
     * @param int $quantity contains the quantity of the item to add
     * @param int $variation_id
     * @param array $variation attribute values
     * @param array $cart_item_data extra cart item data we want to pass into the item
     * @return string|bool $cart_item_key
     */
    public function add_to_cart( $product_id = 0, $quantity = 1, $variation_id = 0, $variation = array(), $cart_item_data = array() ) {
        [...]
    }
```

See full Docs in the [Woocommerce Subscriptions FAQ](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/subscriptions/faq/)